# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 scheduled export to MS Access

Tags: sql, database, scheduled-tasks

Experts !!

I am not familiar with SQL Server Management Studio and never had to schedule tasks on an SQL Server.

I am exporting my database to MS Access everyday. I need Management Studio to do this automatically everyday at 2:00 am.

Any ideas.

[image]

Comment: If you have the data in a real database, why are you exporting it to MS Access?  Even if you have an application that uses Access, you can link from Access into the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff With a table named "FollowUp" I think they're likely to be ... following something up. First thing that came to my mind was a mobile sales force visiting customers who might not have access to the Internet. Linked tables break down as latency to the remote server approaches infinity :-)

Comment: Good point.  But I'm still biased acess MS Access.  I don't mean to offend anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**On the wizard screen that you are using to export data, select the Save SSIS Package option, the next screen will give you the options to save that package. Then go to SQL Server Agent and schedule that package**

[image]
[image]

**Right click on Jobs and select New Job**

[image]

**Give the Job a name and description**

[image]

**Select Steps, Name the step, select SSIS as the Type, select the Package source and then select your Package**

[image]

**Schedule the job**

[image]

Comment: +1 Nailed it. But a minor note: you can't save packages if you're using Management Studio Express.

Comment: I didn't know that, but also have never used express version myself :-)

Comment: i didn't try it yet, but looks like it will work fine :) thank You

Comment: Yeah it will work, if you run into any problems they'll most likely be related to server permissions, so you may need to use a service account