# Restore Compact Edition .SDF into Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, database-restore

**EDIT :**
It turned out that this can only be done through an external tool like [this](http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html) 
tool thanks to ErikEJ answer.

But it can't be automated through a SQL Job or SSIS Import Package till the moment of writing.

The situation might be different in future/recesnt SQL Editions I am using SQL Server 2008 Standard.

**The Question :**

Is there a way to restore Compact Edition **.SDF** into Standard Edition
So far I tried this

```
use [master]
go
restore filelistonly from disk='C:\113\DB_Files\file.sdf'
go
```

It gives this

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The media family on device
>   'C:\113\DB_Files\file.sdf' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot
>   process this media family. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE
>   FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

Comment: A `sdf` file isn't a backup... Try the first link on Google: http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=upgrade+sql+server+compact+to+sql+server&oq=upgrade+sql+server+compact+to+sql+server&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...495.495.0.671.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.UhDWwF8uyj4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d85bc23abb3691b5&biw=1920&bih=979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "restore", but you can migrate using some of my tools for example: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html

Comment: I was actually hoping for something that can be put into an SQL Server Job to automate the process, because my situation requires me to do this migration daily or even hourly, but Thanks anyway

Comment: @ElemeenElsayed You can use SSIS for this. Eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861955/sql-server-management-studio-2008-scheduled-export-to-ms-access

Comment: But cant be put into a stored procedure can they?

Comment: No, you can run via a SQL Agent job, and start the job from a stored procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx