# Get data from SQL server 2008r2 to mysql automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, replication

I have a web interface (php front end, mysql backend) running in the same domain as a sql server database. I need to frequently (daily or weekly) query sql server and then load that data into mysql. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `SQL Server Agent` to run a scheduled job that would select and export the data direct to your MySQL server.

Like this example ([SQL Server Management Studio 2008 scheduled export to MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861955/sql-server-management-studio-2008-scheduled-export-to-ms-access)), but exporting to MySQL instead of MS Access

Comment: that makes sense. And to automate the 2nd half?

Comment: I would use the Agent job to perform both halves, that is to `SELECT` the data from SQL Server and to `INSERT` it into MySQL