# Schedule exports to Text file

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, export

I have a normal SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM fmain
```

and I want the result of this query to be saved into a text file on a regular basis.

That is to say I want the query to run itself and then populate the text file every morning at 8 AM (or so).

I am running `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`, and am a novice SQL user, so please try and answer in as much explanatory fashion as possible.

Please help me solve this.

Cheers,
Nils

Comment: Via SSIS Job: Right click the DB, Tasks->Export Data and then follow these steps: [SQL Server Management Studio 2008 scheduled export to MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861955/sql-server-management-studio-2008-scheduled-export-to-ms-access)

Answer (score 2):

you can do that with a Sql script, a batch and a scheduled Task.

First of all, create the Sql Script in your preferred directory, for example **C:\TEMP\MySelect.sql**, with your sql statement.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S . -d YOUR_DATABASE_NAME -Q "EXEC SELECT * FROM fmain" -s "," -o "C:\TEMP\MY_FILE.txt" -h-1 -W -s"|"';
```

Then create the batch file, like **C:\TEMP\call_sql.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
echo "Start"
sqlcmd -i C:\TEMP\MySelect.sql
```

Then configure the Task Scheduler to run every morning at 8 AM.
You can do that by the program interface or using a script:

```
schtasks /create /sc DAILY /ST 08:00  /tn "EXPORT fMain every DAY Script" /tr "C:\TEMP\call_sql.bat"
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, however i am getting a lot of errors on the EXEC line. The entire line is more or less red :P. I changed the database name to my database, is there anything else i need to be cautious concerning this?

Comment: Can you post the error?
check if C:\TEMP\ directory exist(or the directory path where you want to save your file)